# problem in listview not clickable

Tags: android, listview, click

Hello i a probleme i use getListView(); for my list1 and i would like use a second list view (this separating by tab)

My fist listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

/>

For my second listview I is not found another solution, i use id

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

/>

the problem is when use

```
((ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2)).setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){...
```

The listview is not clickable, the first listview good work !

When i use

```
getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){...
```

(already used for listview list1 i know..) the listview 2 is clickable but the setOnScrollListener for the list 1 doesn't work  ....

how use two getListView() or fixed this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want onScrollListener? or did you want onItemClickListener? in either case, there is no reason something like this shouldn't work:

```
ListView lv1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
ListView lv2=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);

lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){...
lv1.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){...

lv2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){...
lv2.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){...
```

Comment: the listview make clickable if i remove the `lv2.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){`
i need setOnScrollListener for load dinamique listview (work)
The setOnScrollListener work if i replace lv2 by getListView() but this is used by listview 1

Comment: idem for android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Comment: Why my second listview is not clickable lv2.setOnScrollListener 
why ListView lv2=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2); no work !!!

Comment: nothing to see , if i remove Adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged(); in lv2.setOnScrollListener, the listiew2 becomes clickable ????